# Is it possible to return seq when using Array2D?

Tags: f#

I want to gather the non zero element of a matrix into a `sequence<(row,column,value)>`

This doesn't work

```
let getSparseMatrixCOO matrix =
    seq {
          matrix |> Array2D.iteri (fun row column elem -> 
                                    if elem <> 0.0 then yield (row, column, elem)
                                  )
        }
```

Do I have to give up the idea of using `Array2D.iteri`?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `yield` inside a lambda function like this. The `yield` keyword is only usable directly in the scope of the sequence expression (although your attempt has a good logic).

I think the easiest option is to iterate over the elements of the array and write something like this:

```
let getSparseMatrixCOO matrix =
  seq { for row in 0 .. Array2D.length1 matrix - 1 do
          for column in 0 .. Array2D.length2 matrix - 1 do
            let elem = matrix.[row, column]
            if elem <> 0.0 then yield (row, column, elem) }
```

The `Array2D` module does not provide many functions, but it can be extended to include `foldi` function (similar to `Array.foldi`). The function aggregates elements of the array and calls a function you specify for every element. You can then choose elements you want and aggregate them in a way you want.

The following uses a list as a state and appends non-zero elements to the list during aggregation:

```
Array2D.foldi (fun row column elem state -> 
  if elem <> 0.0 then (row, column, elem)::state else state) []
```

The missing `Array2D.foldi` function can be implemented (imperatively, to keep it simple) like this:

```
module Array2D =
  let foldi f a matrix = 
    let mutable state = a
    for row in 0 .. Array2D.length1 matrix - 1 do
      for column in 0 .. Array2D.length2 matrix - 1 do
        state <- f row column (matrix.[row, column]) state
    state
```

Answer (score 1):

You may continue sticking to `Array2D.iteri` with something like

```
let getSparseMatrixCOO matrix =
    let result = ref List<int*int*float>.Empty
    matrix |> Array2D.iteri(fun i j elem -> if elem <> 0.0 then result := (i,j,elem)::!result)
    !result |> List.rev
```

if laziness of your original intent does not matter as the snippet above will give you the same sequence, only eagerly.